# undefined reference compiler error in c++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, undefined-reference

I am getting the error message below when I try to compile my code -

> In function
>   '__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
>   home/user/main.cpp:50: undefined
>   reference to
>   'PhysEng2D::PhysEng2D(void)'

The only code on line 50 is -

```
PhysEng2D Physics;
```

The header file for PhysEng2D is -

```
#ifndef _PHYSENG2D_H_ 
#define _PHYSENG2D_H_ 

#include "primitives.h"

class PhysEng2D
{
public:

    PhysEng2D::PhysEng2D(); 
    PhysEng2D::~PhysEng2D();

    bool IsBoundingBoxCollision(PS2Sprite & S1, PS2Sprite & S2); 

    bool IsWallCollision(PS2Sprite & S); 

}; 

#endif
```

And the beginning of the rest of PhysEng2D is -

```
#include "primitives.h"
#include "physeng2d.h" 


PhysEng2D::PhysEng2D()
{
    //Nothing to Initialise 
}

PhysEng2D::~PhysEng2D()
{
    //Nothing to clean up
}
```

(I didn't include the methods in full because I didn't think they were relevant)

Sorry, I am aware that this is probably a very stupid little error that I'm making.

Comment: How are you compiling/linking this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *compile* each cpp file, then *link* them.

```
g++ -c -Wall main.cpp
g++ -c -Wall physeng2d.cpp

g++ -o myapp main.o physeng2d.o
```

You also should remove the `PhysEng2D::` prefix from the class definition in the .h

Comment: I have a makefile, if I use make clean, make depend, make - shouldn't this do it automatically?

Comment: @ShimmerGeek: That all depends on whether your Makefile is correct or not.

Comment: It was working okay with all the other includes and stuff, until I added the PhysEng2D.h / PhysEng2D.cpp

Comment: Do I need to do something else?

Comment: @ShimmerGeek: More or less. Typically you add the .cpp to SOURCES and create OBJECTS from SOURCES like this: `OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)`

Answer (score 6):

Your constructor and destructor in the header file should not contain the name of the class.

Change

```
PhysEng2D::PhysEng2D(); 
PhysEng2D::~PhysEng2D();
```

To

```
PhysEndg2D();
~PhysEng2D();
```

And you don't need to reinclude "primitives.h" in the .cpp.

Comment: Thanks. I actually thought it was wrong to write PhysEng2D::PhysEng2D(); rather than just PhysEng2D(); but I checked one of the provided examples and it had it the former way! Oh well, guess I should learn to trust my instincts ;) 

And yeah, I was pretty sure I didn't need to reinclude "primitives.h" in the .cpp but at that point I figured changing anything else would only make the source of the bug even more confusing to locate!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah, don't worry, you get used to this kind of things very quickly. Just keep the include to the header file in the cpp file, and put every other needed includes for this class in the header.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you forgot to link `PhysEng2D.o` with `main.o`. Also `PhysEng2D::PhysEng2D();` syntax isn't valid inside the class definition: It should just say `PhysEng2D();`.

Comment: Oh frak... I can't believe I didn't notice the latter. 

As for the former... I have #include "PhysEng2D.h"; in the main.cpp file also - sorry, forgot to include that :) 

Think it is the PhysEng2D::PhysEng2D(); syntax that is the problem?